# How disable canonical redirect wp-signup

Tags: htaccess

I use wordpress 4.9.8.
I want to close user access to site.com/wp-signup.php
I added code in .htaccess

```
<Files wp-signup.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

When I go to site.com/wp-signup.php, I get error 403.It's good for me.

But if I follow the link /wp-signup and /wp-signup.ph and /wp-signup.p etc I get the following error:

[image]

This error is formed from a file - wp-includes/functions.php line 2722.
How to display 403 error with any link /wp-signup ?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<Files>` directive is used to target specific files on the filesystem, not URLs. To change this to target any *URL* that starts `/wp-signup` then use mod_rewrite instead. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-signup - [F]
```

This must go at the top of your `.htaccess` file.